# "Docker Desktop stopped..." message after installation

Tags: docker, installation

Installed docker desktop for windows, after having installed the linux kernel update package and changing to wsl 2 version (virtualization is enabled) but i get the message "Docker Desktop stopped..." as shown below.

Tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling again
- run application as administrator

[image]

Comment: For me restarting docker from the taskbar tray fixed the issue.

Comment: In my case it started working after installing: "WSL2 Linux kernel update package for x64 machines". More info here: https://superuser.com/questions/1584710/docker-wsl-2-installation-is-incomplete

Comment: First, I had to update the kernel ( https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5650#issuecomment-663845956 ). Then I went to Debug -> Clean / Purge Data -> WSL 2 -> Delete. Then It worked.

Comment: Debug -> Clean / Purge Data -> WSL 2 -> Delete also worked for me on Win10. Thanks.

Comment: Enable **Virtualization** for your system.

Comment: In my case I had to install the [linux kernel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-manual#step-4---download-the-linux-kernel-update-package). Make sure you have installed at least a distribution from [Microsoft store](https://aka.ms/wslstore)

Comment: In my case, i had to enable virtualization in CPU config tab in vcenter for my win10 virtual machine.

Comment: Run wsl --update from the command prompt

Comment: Make sure HyperV is installed from Windows Optional Features. It won't autoinstalll when install WSL.

Comment: im not sure why do people use docker, their support is pathetic with the software they have built. I have been trying to use it since last 3 days, so many errors popping up, taking so much time and memory. I think its just not worth it

Comment: in my case, I've opened the PowerShell and provided the command: "Get-Service vmcompute | Restart-Service". After that, I've started the docker as admin, and it worked.

Answer (score 18):

From https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12545#issuecomment-1037225140

> Just go to the config file at `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Docker\settings.json`, and set `"wslEngineEnabled": true`

I had to restart after saving.

Comment: This solved the problem with my machine. I noticed that when I opened the settings in the app itself when it showed that it stopped, the WSL engine was not checked. That led me here. Nice find.

I have an XPS 9500 running Windows 11 Home.

Comment: Thank you for you .I solved this problem.

Comment: Works perfectly for Docker v4.5

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: This setting `wslEngineEnabled` was set to true but I still faced issues.

Comment: My issue is on Mac :sad

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: In my experience, Docker on Windows goes "stale" after a while or under certain circumstances. It may seem obvious or you might have already tried it, but for me easiest solution is usually to just reboot the machine.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. If you are using docker 4.5.0, try uninstall and install 4.4.4 instead. That worked for me.

Comment: additionaly i had to enable virtualization in the bios and update linux kernel

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: This worked for me. I installed 4.6.0 for windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 3):

A [new version of Docker Desktop (4.5.1)](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-451), released on 2022-02-15 fixes this problem.

> If you are running Docker Desktop on Windows Home, installing 4.5.1 will switch it back to WSL 2 automatically. If you are running another version of Windows, and you want Docker Desktop to use the WSL 2 backend, you must manually switch by enabling the Use the WSL 2 based engine option in the Settings > General section. Alternatively, you can edit the Docker Desktop settings file located at %APPDATA%\Docker\settings.json and manually switch the value of the wslEngineEnabled field to true.

Comment: It doesn't fix it. I installed after 2/15 and I'm still experiencing this.

Comment: This doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this issue on Mac (Intel chip) after updating to v4.5.0.

Reinstalling the desktop app and a system restart solved the issue.

Comment: That's not a solution, that' a nuke.

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy I assume he means reinstalling Docker, not the OS.

Comment: Oops - have specified I reinstalled the desktop app not the whole system as a fix

Answer (score 0):

I also get the same problem after updating my Docker version from 4.4.4 to 4.5. It was crashed when I want to run my container today. I try to reinstall with 4.5 version and get the error "Docker Desktop stopped...". Then, I try to reinstall with 4.4.4 version, and now it just run perfectly fine like before.

Comment: This doesn't work.